# How do I run a scheduled task on Google App Engine on-demand?

Tags: google-app-engine, scheduled-tasks

I would like to run a scheduled task on-demand in my production appspot.  Unlike development, there is no "run this task" button that I can click.  When I try to go to the URL directly, I get a 500 error.  The logs say this:

> Authentication for the Google Apps domain webfilings.com can only be
>   performed when requests are served from a subdomain of that domain or
>   it has been approved through the Google Apps Control Panel

I have verified that I am logged in and that I am an owner of this appspot.

I also tried running the task via the remote api tool but this doesn't work either.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there is currently no "Run Now" button for Cron tasks. This is a reasonable feature request if you would like to file it.

Comment: I've added a feature request here http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8792&thanks=8792&ts=1360244457 please vote for it if you think its worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

The authentication error is due to how your application is configured.
This will happen if you have set the Authentication Type (when creating an app or in the application settings) to Google Apps Domain. This causes the app to require that all login be done using an account managed by that domain, but also requires that the domain administrator configure the applicaiton in the Google Apps control panel.
You (or your domain adminstrator) can do this by going to the application settings for the application on appengine.google.com and clicking Add Domain. You can also reset the Authentication Type to Google Accounts API which will allow all accounts.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/auth has more information, though it's now permitted to change authentication types under certain conditions.

Comment: The domain I am logged in with and the domain listed are the same.  I am also the owner of this app.